# JSON data parser doesn't allow single-quote

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I am writing "comments" from my website in my database with PHP using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. this will escape stuff out, as well as single-quote (') and double-quotes ("). when I load these comments back into my website, I'm using AJAX to load them, triggered by the scroll bar of a DIV to load 5 more on each scroll bar that reached bottom of DIV.

Everything works fine until an entry containes escaped \' (single-quote)

```
var ajax_entry_items = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
```

the `JSON.parse` function gives the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in Google Chrome.

How can I still input single-quotes and double-quotes in my comments in my database and bring them back to display them on the website ? The double-quotes and single-quotes come back escaped but for some reason the single-quote, escaped, generates the

> Unexpected token" error.

Thanks.

Comment: Run your text through the JSON validator. It can help in debugging issues like this. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not allowed to enclose strings in single quotes, nor to escape single quotes, in JSON. You must escape double quotes and must not escape single quotes.

Comment: true...for people needing to still have escaped \' \" in their tables but still use for JSON when getting them see the small woraround i did in the latter comments. It works now. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the data you're outputting from the database with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I did a small workaround like this : $comment_text_updated = str_replace("\'","'",$comment_text); which will replace the \' with ' so keeping the rest text escaped, since the error was only with the escaped ' (single-quote) and now it works. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You have no guarantee that this will work with all special chars your string might contain, however. It's always advisable to rely on functions designed for this very purpose. To escape for MySQL, you're using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. To escape for Javascript, you should escape with `json_encode()`. The data you store in the database will typically never be escaped.

Comment: I'm escaping with mysql_real_escape and saving it escaped in the database..what you're saying is that i should save it unescaped? How? Since i'm escaping it :)

Comment: Please give me an example of characters that should jam my ajax reader from the table which builds json style output that i parse and use as variables....i tried inputting from my ipad all characters that looked special beside letters and numbers and it worked just fine...it seems that my major problem was the escaped single quote that i grabbed from the table *i save stuff escaped in the table and do stripslashes(htmlspecialchars to output back

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes the data to be injected in your SQL (text) query. The data itself, once interpreted by the RDBMS, will be stored unescaped. Load the data from your DB and see by yourself.